# NodeJS not receiving full tcp packet when data comes in buffer format from iot devices

Tags: node.js, tcp, hex, iot, tcpdump

We have an IOT device for real-time communication (GPS location). 
The device is sending TCP packets to the Nodejs server. But when we receiving so it is in buffer format and stripped.
We use tcpdump to checking, what data is coming in the network/transport layer. And Data is in HEX format.

```
0x0000:  029e 280b b191 022c 1666 c6e4 0800 4500  ..(....,.f....E.
0x0010:  0061 0ae6 0000 6706 b735 6b54 5c96 ac1f  .a....g..5kT\...
0x0020:  1d72 5478 0c08 bc9e fa71 4bff c417 5010  .rTx.....qK...P.
0x0030:  03c4 2571 0000 aa55 0035 8305 4572 0051  ..%q...U.5..Er.Q
0x0040:  7601 0101 0209 e55e cde4 eb5e cde4 eb18  v......^...^....
0x0050:  fb48 6dcb c14a 0f00 0040 6c00 0000 1001  .Hm..J...@l.....
0x0060:  4d08 2001 9aff be8f 0d00 000a 0000 00    M..............
```

But, NodeJS server is receiving data in below format:
Buffer aa 55 00 35 83 05 45 72 00 51 76 01 01 01 02 0a d8 5e ce 02 58 5e ce 02 58 18 fb 3e b3 cb c1 4d 3f 00 00 3f e7 00 00 00 10 00 fb 0c 20 01 9a ff bc 8f ...

So why we are not able to receive full data packets? Because we need full data packets for send acknowledgment purposes.

```
var net = require('net');
net.createServer(function (socket) { 
    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        var text = data.toString('hex');
        console.log("data in hex", text);
    });
    socket.on('end', function() {
        console.log('end'); 
    });
    socket.on('close', function() {
        console.log('close');
    });
    socket.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('error ', e); 
    }); 

    }).listen(3080, function() { 
        console.log('TCP Server is listening on port 3080'); 
    });
});
```

Note: Sorry, My English is very poor.

Comment: Are you saying that the rest of the data never arrives or just that the data does arrive, but is split into separate incoming chunks?  TCP data can arrive in any size packet, regardless of how it was sent.  It is up to the recipient of the data to recombine arriving data chunks into a complete message that can be used or use a pre-built protocol that does that for you (such as webSocket).

Comment: Yes, first part of data never arrives.

Comment: Well, we're going to have to see both sending and receiving code as the problem could be on either end.   It's possible that some data arrives before you have a listener for the `data` event.  Also possible sending of the data is not being done correctly.  Not much we can offer without more code.

Comment: Actually, As I described, the Sending data process is not our part because data is coming to an IoT device. We are just listening (or receiving) data.
var net = require('net');net.createServer(function (socket) {
socket.on('data', function(data) {var text = data.toString('hex');console.log("data in hex", text);});
socket.on('end', function() {console.log('end'); });socket.on('close', function() {console.log('close');});socket.on('error', function(e) {console.log('error ', e); });
}).listen(3080, function() {
  console.log('TCP Server is listening on port 3080');
});

Comment: Please do not put multi-line code in comments here as it is not readable and may not be seen by others reading your question.  Please use the "edit" link below your question to add the code to your question, format it properly as code and then leave a comment that you've edited your question to include the code.

Comment: That  code looks like it will display anything that is sent to your server.  Either you are misunderstanding the data that you have and it is already a full data packet or there is a problem on the sending side, not here.

Comment: If it sending side problems than I should not able to receive full data packets in the network/transport layer.

Comment: I guess I'm confused then.  Are you saying that the network layer has a full packet, but your node.js code is not receiving all the data you see in the network layer?

Comment: Yes, exactly right.

Comment: There is nothing in your nodejs code that indicates that would be possible if this your entire real code.  I think it's likely that either you are confused about what you are receiving in node.js or this isn't your actual real code and there's something you are not disclosing to us that is causing you a problem.  Not much else we can do with what you're showing us.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue, when Buffer string is too long and you Log it,
it appears some like `ff ... 2 more bytes>`.

I managed getting back my entire string by converting the Buffer to Hex.

```
var net = require('net');
net.createServer(function (socket) { 
    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        const hexData = data.toString('hex')
        console.log("data in hex", hexData);
    });
  })
```